Create Render Blueprint From Docker-Compose
Here is the link to my repo: https://github.com/RohanAlmighty/Python-Docker-NSE-Fetcher
Can someone help me by writing the correct render.yaml from the docker-compose.yaml
I tried following the Render Blueprint Docs, but I am new to both Render as well as Docker and could not figure out much.
 
Docker Compose :
networks:

  default:
    name: nse-net

services:

  python-fastapi-quote:
    build:
      context: ./quote
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: python-fastapi-quote
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    command: python ./app/main.py
    container_name: python-fastapi-quote

  python-fastapi-search:
    build:
      context: ./search
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: python-fastapi-search
    ports:
      - "8002:8002"
    command: python ./app/main.py
    container_name: python-fastapi-search

  python-fastapi-fetcher:
    build:
      context: ./fetcher
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: python-fastapi-fetcher
    ports:
      - "8001:8001"
    command: python ./app/main.py
    container_name: python-fastapi-fetcher

Render YAML :
services:
  - type: web
    name: python-fastapi-quote
    runtime: docker
    dockerfilePath: ./quote/Dockerfile
    - key: PORT
      value: 8000
  - type: web
    name: python-fastapi-search
    runtime: docker
    dockerfilePath: ./search/Dockerfile
    - key: PORT
      value: 8002
  - type: web
    name: python-fastapi-fetcher
    runtime: docker
    dockerfilePath: ./fetcher/Dockerfile
    - key: PORT
      value: 8001



Looks like you forgot envVars:?
services:
  - type: web
    name: python-fastapi-quote
    runtime: docker
    dockerfilePath: ./quote/Dockerfile
    envVars:
    - key: PORT
      value: 8000
  - type: web
    name: python-fastapi-search
    runtime: docker
    dockerfilePath: ./search/Dockerfile
    envVars:
    - key: PORT
      value: 8002
  - type: web
    name: python-fastapi-fetcher
    runtime: docker
    dockerfilePath: ./fetcher/Dockerfile
    envVars:
    - key: PORT
      value: 8001


This might be correct, unfortunately now Render asks me for my Credit Card. I thought Render Blueprint was free. :(

Can't help with that, sorry!
